# Can't find generateFixtureXml.php file in Magento 2.3 for Functional Testing Framework

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

According to the official documentation of Magento 2.3, we can generate fixtures executing this command. For example:

```
php -f generateFixtureXml.php -- --name widget --entity_type widget_instance --collection Magento\\Widget\\Model\\Resource\\Widget\\Instance\\Collection
```

but I can't find this file in the dev/tests/functional/util folder.

The url for the documentation is https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mtf/create_test/create_new_test.html

Where is this file?